# How to reuse a same Navigation Drawer in different activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

My drawer is created by android studio automatically and I realized that its structure is not as it was like when I created handly. API23 suggests developers to use assembled layout files. How can I use the same drawer in different activities with API23?

Answer (score 0):

create xml of only drawer component and include it in every activity layout.
    After that to write java code of drawer create CommonActivity class which extends activity and write here drawer now user CommonActivity rather than extending Activity class in every activity class

like

```
public class CommonActivity extends Activity
{
oncreate
{
//drawer code
}
}

public class YourActivity extends CommonActivity
{

//No need to write drawer code here again
}
```